# Issue with calling instance method from handwritten javascript

Tags: gwt, jsni

Can anyone help with what is wrong in the code below(based on the answers to a similar question asked on SO):

```
    public String javaMethod(String input) {
        return "it works";
}

    public native void defineBridgeMethod() /*-{ 
        var that = this;
        $wnd.jsFunction= $entry(function(msg) {
                 that.@com.myclass.ClassName::javaMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)(msg)
            });
    }-*/;
```

The issue is that Javascript does not find jsFunction: alert(jsFunction) in Javascript code returns 'undefined'.

Thanks.

Edit: Huh, one hour later: figured out that I just needed to have `that.@com...` returned!

Comment: So your question is answered? If so, answer your own question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh, one hour later: figured out that I just needed to have `that.@com...` returned!

The bridge method should be:

```
public native void defineBridgeMethod() /*-{ 
    var that = this;
    $wnd.jsFunction= $entry(function(msg) {
             return that.@com.myclass.ClassName::javaMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)(msg)
        });
}-*/;
```

Comment: I don't get what "var this = that" really does, but it works - while this.@... does not.

Comment: It has something to do with scoping. `this` within that function is another one than outside the function. You circumvent that by assigning the outer `this` to a variable which is also "visible" within the function statement.