# GWT - Calling instance method from external javascript

Tags: gwt, jsni

There is this $entry method that we can use in GWT to allow external javascript to execute java methods.
You can see the explanations in their documentation https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI?hl=fr#calling

However, the example there is only with static methods. I'm trying to write it for a non-static method and when I try to call it, I get an exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject$ to mypackage.MyModule
```

Here is my code :

```
public native void setRefreshModuleCallback() /*-{
    $wnd.refreshModule = $entry(function() {
        this.@mypackage.MyModule::refreshModuleJava();
        alert('test');
    });
}-*/;

public void refreshModuleJava() {
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, "REFRESH");
}
```

What I find very funny is that alert is called, I see the result in the browser, but the call just before is not performed.

Do you know if it's actually possible to do such thing ?

Comment: Note that I had a look at this post and it didn't help (or I missed something) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676960/issue-with-calling-instance-method-from-handwritten-javascript

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$entry` is not about *calling java*, it's about ensuring a few things go well in GWT: exceptions are routed to the `GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler`, and commands scheduled *via* `Scheduler#scheduleEntry` and `Scheduler#scheduleFinally` are correctly called.

Your problem is the `this`. When the function is called, `this` is not your `MyModule` class (it's most probably the `$wnd` object). This is why the question you linked to uses `var that = this`. It's about *scoping*.

You also need to actually *call* the method, not only reference it: in JSNI, the first pair of parens are for the formal parameters (to disambiguate overloads), and you need another pair passing the actual arguments: `that.@mypackage.MyModule::refreshModuleJava()()`.

Comment: I tried with 'var that = this;' and calling 'that.@mypackage.MyModule::refreshModuleJava();' and still get the same behavior

Comment: Updated answer with additional info, but that `var that = this` should have at least make the error disappear.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Exhaustive explanation. You saved my day.